# getting ` x509: certificate signed by unknown authority` error while verifying certificates for rest application

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, ssl-certificate, client-certificates

I am generating a self signed certificate using openssl in Ubuntu. I want to use it for localhost rest server. But while verification, I am getting error : `x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`, can anyone please tell me how I can resolve this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Place your .crt certificate to /usr/share/ca-certificates

Edit /etc/ca-certificates.conf and add your certificate name there.
(Look at `update-ca-certificates` man page for more information.)

Then run `sudo update-ca-certificates`

Works for me in Ubuntu 22

Comment: My system needed a `systemctl restart myservice` as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

Place your root certificate and intermediate (if you have one) in /usr/share/local/ca-certificates with the .crt extension.

Run:

```
sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
1 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

In this case, curl is your friend:

```
curl -Iv https://localhost/path/to/api
```

Also you can run openssl s_client

```
openssl s_client localhost:443
```

Additionally, you can interrogate your certificate by providing your certificate:

```
openssl s_client -connect localhost:443 -CAfile /path/to/your/cert.pem
```

If you certificate does not match, you know.  Possibly you are using the wrong certificate for your REST API or the certificate is not being installed, which you can verify by looking in /etc/ssl/certs directory on your system (if you are running Linux)

Comment: tried, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

In the official documentation, they mentioned the error and how to solve it.

> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
> [ERROR ImagePull]: failed to pull image registry.k8s.io/kube-apiserver:v1.13.3:
> output: Error response from daemon:
> Get https://registry.k8s.io/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
> This is because minikube VM is stuck behind a proxy that rewrites HTTPS responses to contain its own TLS certificate. The solution is to install the proxy certificate into a location that is copied to the VM at startup, so that it can be validated.
>
> Ask your IT department for the appropriate PEM file, and add it to:
>
> ~/.minikube/files/etc/ssl/certs
>
> or
>
> ~/.minikube/certs
>
> Then run minikube delete and minikube start

Then I discovered where my company keep the .pem files, then I executed the next commands:

```
cp /etc/pki/ca-trust/source/anchors/* ~/.minikube/certs/
minikube delete --all
minikube start
```

if you`re not behind a proxy/vpn, then you need to generate a ssl certificate as Randall Svancara explained in the answer above and then put the cert file in the ~/.minikube/certs directory.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Create file `daemon.json` in /etc/docker/
inside put this:

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["docker-registry-machine-name:443","docker-registry-machine-name:80","0.0.0.0/0"]
}
```

and save it.
After that with jenkins user run this command:
git config --global http.sslVerify "false"
Then restart Jenkins and should work.